# Getting always error 404 on jsonp request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404, jsonp

I ran into an issue while trying to retrieve some jsonp data from another Host. That's my setup:

Client on 192.168.2.107 running on Raspbian

Host on 192.168.2.109 running apache2 on raspbian

Client is able to get the web Page pump.php from Host via Web Browser.

Code on Client:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://192.168.2.109/pump.php',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success:function(result)        {
             console.log(result);
           },
   error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
            console.log(xhr);
            alert(thrownError + xhr.status);
         }
});
```

Code on server (pump.php):

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo "myCall({foo:'bar'});";
```

I always get a 404 response from the host. Though I'm completely out of ideas what's wrong with my code or something else or even how I should try to troubleshoot this, any help is higly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] Forgot to mention that myCall() is specified in the client as well:

```
function myCall(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Your content type should be a JavaScript content type. e.g. `application/javascript`

Comment: 404 error means the URL is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to allow your ip on the host php page:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.2.107');
```

Comment: 404 error means the URL doesn't exist. So the script never runs, and it doesn't matter what you put in the script.

Comment: This isn't needed for JSONP, it's only needed for AJAX.